# Differentiate the same Listener in a different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently working on Tabhost + fragment app

Assume there are two tabs only.  That means there are two fragments, but the two fragment are also implementing the listener like this:

```
public class TabA extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

sensorManager = (SensorManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener)ctx,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL); 


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // assign directions

        // check sensor type
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {


        }

    }
}
```

The problem is it seems the two listeners are not independent. The TabA one will interfere with the Tab B one, or vice versa. So how can I make the two listeners independent? Thanks